# twitter-bootstrap-3 Panels do not display in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am starting to use Bootstrap with ASP.NET 4.0.

I have imported bootstrap into my project, and added the jQuery script lines shown in the sample code.

Here is the code for the Panel I am trying to add:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Customer ID</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        Customer Id Input
    </div>
</div>
```

The text displays but it is not displayed as a Bootstrap Panel.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. You may have problem from other css or missing bootstrap css. 
It is possible that you have some other css code overrides bootstrap css.

To confirm do inspect element foryour panel element and see what classes that element is using!

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Customer ID</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        Customer Id Input
    </div>
</div>
```

Looks like some thing is wrong with your html format:

Comment: Lahar - Thanks for your reply.  I copied your bootstrap link into the code and now it is working !  The bootstrap link I got from the Bootstrap website was "css/bootstrap.mon.css". - Many thanks !

Comment: Yes so you can always look into inspect element and confirm element is using proper css or not. Glad that my answer solve your problem. I will appreciate if you accept & up vote & accept answer if it solves your problem.